# How do I do autocomplete search in a textbox?

Tags: c#, autocomplete

I have a list of account numbers that I want show when a user type in a textbox.  I am getting `InvalidCastException was unhandled`.

Example of my code:

```
  private void TextBoxAutoComplete()
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection myCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        List<AccountsVOL> avo = acctBAL.searchByAccountNOBAL(txtAccountNo.Text);
        if (avo.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (AccountsVOL vo in avo)
            {
                myCollection.Add(vo.AccountNumber);
            }
            txtAccountNo.AutoCompleteCustomSource = myCollection;
        }
    }
```

Stack trace:

> at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid&
>   clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid) at 
>   System.Windows.Forms.StringSource..ctor(String[] strings) at 
>   System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.SetAutoComplete(Boolean reset) at 
>   System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.set_AutoCompleteCustomSource(AutoCompleteStringColl‌​ection
>   value)

Comment: Can you show your stack trace where you're getting the invalid cast exception? My guess is that vo.AccountNumber is the wrong type, but hard to know without the trace.

Comment: Hi Brian - where can I get the stack trace?  AccountNumber is of type string.  I am able to view values from myCollection.

Comment: The stack trace is a property of the exception, so if you are debugging you can click "View Details" on the exception and see it there. Otherwise you can log it or output it to stdout via Console.Write.

Comment: at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.StringSource..ctor(String[] strings)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.SetAutoComplete(Boolean reset)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.set_AutoCompleteCustomSource(AutoCompleteStringCollection value)

Comment: @Nate Better to edit your question and add it there.

Comment: A couple of things before any deep dives - make sure txtAccountNo.AutoCompleteSource is set to AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource and txtAccountNo.AutoCompleteMode is set to AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend BEFORE you assign to txtAccountNo.AutoCompleteCustomSource. Also, you might have problems if your code is not executing on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: At which line you're getting the error?

Comment: @Brian - I set the AutoCompleteSource  = CustomSource and  AutoCompleteMode = SuggestAppend in the properties.

Comment: @Alex - I'm getting the error on the last line - txtAccountNo.AutoCompleteCustomSource = myCollection;